# How can I restrict access to certain URLs by source IP in Tomcat?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6, access-control

I want to restrict access to certain URLs in my Tomcat webapp. 
Only 3 known IP addresses should be allowed access to URLs that fit a certain pattern.

e.g. `http://example.com:1234/abc/personId`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you deciding whether to deny or permit access? By IP? By logged in user? By geographical region? Why do you have iptables in there? iptables is not aware of a URL that may be in use. What stack is running your web server and at which point in your network architecture do you wish to deny access?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking about. Is this machine a web server and you're trying to restrict access to URLs it serves? Or is this machine a NAT box? Or reverse proxy?

Comment: by ip. I have three ips from only I need the access. I want to ban all other ips from using the api.

Comment: System is centos and I'm using apache and tomcat. iptables is there in it.

Comment: @Cheekysoft Actually my site provides information to some apps. But there are a few api I need to ban from public access. 
http://example.com:1234/abc/(personId) like this.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes. This is a webserver. Yes I want to deny some of the api urls it serves from public.

Comment: Then do it in the configuration for the web server software.

Answer (score 12):

Use org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter and map it to the URL you wish to protect. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter for configuration details.

Comment: my url starts with a port! its not working for me. I added the following lines in server.xml
 
   <filter> 
      <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>122\.167\.211\.31</param-value>  ##my ip
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern> ## for http://example.com:1234/abc/(personId)
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Filters aren't defined in server.xml, they are defined in web.xml. Treat it as a normal servlet filter.

Comment: Sorry, but your url starts with a port???? And this port is not the tomcat port?? How your api is running on tomcat?

Comment: Yes. It is an another application which listens on 1024. I just gave an example url in the  question. it directs traffic to tomcat. But the thing is there is no filter option in tomcat 6. that is why this is not working. :(

Comment: In Tomcat 6 you can use the equivalent Valve:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with this in server.xml:

```
 <Valve
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        deny="117.40.83.*,122.224.95.*,119.255.28.*,218.8.245.*,218.85.139.*,219.117.197.*,124.89.39.*,58.18.172.*,180.153.225.*"
        />
```

(these are real IP addresses: owners, you know why :-|) but as you can see it is really a blocker not an enabler. A better solution would be to put Apache HTTPD in front of it with Deny All and Allow From statements, which will let you allow only the 3 IP addresses you need to access the service.

Comment: You can only add Valves to Container elements (Engine, Host, Context). You can restrict them to a subset of URLs within an application. For that, you need the Filter version.

Comment: Worth noting this answer relates to Tomcat 6. In Tomcat 7 the syntax has changed, as the whole entry is a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this to block ips and if you are behind proxy:

```
<Context path="/manager" docBase="manager" reloadable="true" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"/>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow="<your IP regex>"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't restrict access by IP address, for the following reasons:

- Doing so on say internal addresses, e.g. 10.0.0.0/24, means you implicitly trust this entire range. What happens if it is compromised?
- Not all of your customers can or will be able to get static IP addresses - assuming you might want to allow some customers access.
- Customers behind gateway devices where proxies do not support `x-forwarded-for` headers are going to just have the IP of the gateway device; trusting that IP trusts *everyone* behind the gateway, again assuming you might want to give some customers access.

Instead, if you need to run a system where some calls are only accessible to certain users, I'd use authentication - SSL client side certificates work quite well for this purpose. Alternatively, you could use something like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is my server is providing information to mobile apps. So I have a lot of public api's. I cant block them from public. But there are some private api's also. That should be only accessed from three internal systems. And I cannot add additional authentication mechanisms.